# Error in postgresql func with datatype

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpython

I have a function created as follows:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unpickle (data text)
    RETURNS text[]
AS $$
    import base64
    import pickle

    return pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(data))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX issues_unpickle_tags_index ON issue USING btree (unpickle(tags));
```

I am getting an error when creating the index as - `ERROR:  function unpickle(text[]) does not exist.`

The structure of table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "issue" (
  "id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('issue_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
  "tags" text[] COLLATE "default",
  "description" text COLLATE "default" NOT NULL
)
```

I tried changing the first part to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unpickle (data text[])
    RETURNS text[]
```

Then get the error - `ERROR:  TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list`

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I believe you need to use a GIN index for array types.

Comment: Both errors are obvious. The first is that the function is expecting a text and you are passing a text array. The second is that `b64decode` is expecting a string and you are passing a list of strings. Now what is really important is what are you trying to do?!!! Saving pickled data in an array? It does not make sense.

Comment: Clodoaldo Neto : if I want to just have the index created without error, what do I need to do. This is a open-source project on github with not much documentation, i am trying to debug. So any help appreciated.

Comment: @nobuzz _to just have the index created without error_ you must pass the function a parameter of the type it is expecting, and it is expecting text, not a text array which is the type of `tags`. Why do you think that the `tags` text array is pickled? Post the function that saves data to the `issue` table.